# Check if vector or column/row of *.dat is filled with zero values in gnuplot

Tags: if-statement, sum, gnuplot

In gnuplot, I need to find out if a whole column of my data file is filled with zero values (maybe by summoning up the elements?).

I just found a way to add columns in a plot, but not the column itself. I'd like to write something like

```
if(data(:,1)==zeros) ...
```

or:

```
if(sum(data(:,1))==0) ...
```

How do I address this column outside of "using 1:2 .."? Is there a short way to check this or is the `sum` neccessary?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your whole question. It was hard to read and because of that also hard to understand. I hope the question is now a bit cleaner. Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [the editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to see if you can edit and improve your question according to suggestions mentioned there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you the `stats` function

```
$data <<EOD
1 2 0
2 4 0
3 3 0
3 5 0
EOD

stats $data us 3
print STATS_sum
```

Another more secure way to check, whether nozero values are present, is (remember -1 and 1 could cancel out in the sum)

```
any = 0
fit a $data us 1:(any=any|($3!=0),$1) via a
print any
```

Comment: Instead of `stats $data us 3` it might be better to use `stats $data us (abs($3))`.